# Have WAMP start automatically upon Windows start-up (without logging on or any UAC interference)

Tags: apache, windows-7, wamp, wampserver

I'm looking to have WAMP start when I switch on the computer. Ideally it would start without users even having to log on. I've added WAMP to the start-up in the registry but a user needs to have logged on and UAC is still playing it's annoying part.

Is there a way to accomplish this without logging on or UAC interfering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Follow these instructions to start the appropriate WAMP services on start-up. UAC will not interfere here and there is no need to log in to start your web-server:

1. Log in as an administrator.
2. Start -> Run "services.msc"
3. Right click the service **wampapache** (may also be called **wampapache64**). Go to properties and set start-up type to 'Automatic'
4. If you want MySQL to also be available on startup, then repeat step 3 for **wampmysqld** (or **wampmysqld64**)

[image]

Tried and tested on Windows 7-10

Comment: I'm not sure but I might have forgotten to put the server online (i.e. click "Put Online"). Might have been something else. It's fixed now.

Comment: its workin when I access to the localhost but, but if we wanna start the app wampserver ???

Comment: This solution works, however the wamp icon doesn't appear in the taskbar tray. How to fix this?

Comment: This solution works OK, but it only launches one of three wamp-related applications (webserver). There are still databases (mysql, mariadb) and wampmanager to run. Better answer is by sariban, which starts wampmanager with all three instances at once at computer startup.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia the answer describe only how to start the `apache` (web server) and `mysql` (database server) services. If you want to the icon (visual interface available in system tray) you need to start automatically `wampmanager.exe` ( <wamp_dir>\wampmanager.exe ) . It requires administrator priviledges so you will have to consider that as well.

Answer (score 40):

1) Open Task Scheduler
2) Under "Action" > Create a Task
3) Give some name
4) Trigger > New > Begin The Task > “At Startup”
5) Actions > New > Browse > c:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
6) Hit OK
7) Restart and Check

Comment: Using the "Any user log in" trigger is much more reiliable.

Comment: the tray icon doesn't appear. ?

Comment: This will work, but it is better to just put services to auto. No need for additional abstraction level.

Comment: It appears to work but there is no icon to show its running, but services are running :-) upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

1) What you need is to create a batch file with path of **wampserver.exe**
2) Make Windows Task Scheduler Run the Batch file
3) Open **Startup:shell** to make the batch file run automatically when the computer Start
4) Disable **UAC** put it on **NERVER NOTIFY** mode so that you don't have message when Wamp Server starts.

I found a blog that gave all the steps plus video here: https://ddroid509ht.blogspot.com/2019/07/open-wamp-server-on-startup.html