# allowing webcam without warning for local application

Tags: javascript, windows, security, webcam

I am building a camera recording application for a museum. The user sits in front of a camera and pushes a button to record a video. Is it possible to  prevent the security warning for using the camera? I am building it in javascript, as a browser application. Thx for advice. Raymond

Comment: Ya, simply get a server(XAMP,WAMP,etc) running on your local and visit your page via server.

Comment: oh, that was fast!! thanks. I tried it, it worked. Now next question then...Is there a way to start all this (wamp + browser-app) automatically at startup?

Comment: For Wamp, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13761553/2575725

Answer (score 1):

will the application be running on a single machine in the museum? If this is the case you will be able to allow the camera to record without the warning by editing the permissions of the browser on that machine, like chrome for instance: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767